# Direct link to Twitter retweet

Tags: twitter

I am working on a Twitter app and I want to find a way to link directly to a retweet.

For example. If user A makes a tweet, and user B retweets it, I want a URL that will take us to user B's profile where the retweet is displayed. What is that unique URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, all Retweets are simply special Tweets. This means each Retweet also has an ID (which is stored on `id` and `id_str` at the root of the Tweet object). [For proof, here's a Retweet from the Twitter Retweets account.](https://twitter.com/twitterretweets/status/1316787822976618496)

If you're using Tweet Streams (e.g. `statuses/filter`), you'll be able to pick up this ID from the returned Tweet object of the retweet. From the ID, you can just build a normal Twitter link with `https://twitter.com/<username>/status/<retweet id>`. Assuming your Retweet object is named `retweet`, the correct link would be (in JavaScript) `` `https://twitter.com/${retweet.user.screen_name}/status/${retweet.id_str}` ``.

If the Retweet is fairly recent, you can do a status search (`search/tweets`) on the user's profile (i.e. you have to set the `q` parameter to `from:<username>`) to find the Retweet. You'll most likely have to cross check the ID of the Tweet you want and the ID of the Retweet you're looking for to be sure, though.

If you're trying to get the Retweet ID of an old Tweet, however, you might have to use Twitter's Premium APIs, which are paid.

Answer (score 7):

I recently needed to get a link to an arbitrary retweet that was too old for the search feature to work.

Here's what I did:

1. Open the [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)
2. Visit the timeline of the retweeter
3. Scroll until you find the retweet
4. Look at the Network Monitor, open the latest request to the endpoint `/UserTweets`
5. Either

   - go to the "Response" tab and sift through its JSON manually to get the `id_str` to craft the URL:
     [image: (parsed data from Twitter /UserTweets endpoint)]
   - or, paste the following into the Console, then right-click on the response, “Copy…Response”, and return to the console to press Enter:

   ```js
   UserTweets = JSON.parse(prompt("Paste the copied Response data:"));

   // get the output from that endpoint,
   UserTweets
   // dig through the packaging,
   ['data']['user']['result']['timeline_v2']['timeline']['instructions']
   // filter out "pinned tweets" metadata,
   .filter(cmd => cmd['type'] == "TimelineAddEntries")
   // de-batch,
   .flatmap(cmd => cmd['entries'])
   // filter out "cursor" metadata,
   .filter(entry => entry['content']['entryType'] == "TimelineTimelineItem" )
   // then dig through a bunch more layers of packaging,
   .map(entry => entry['content']['itemContent']['tweet_results']['result'])
   // munge the tweets into a more-usable format,
   .map(tweet => ({user: tweet['core']['user_results']['legacy'], tweet: tweet['legacy']}))
   // filter out non-retweets,
   .filter(({tweet}) => tweet['retweeted_status_result'])
   // extract just the RT text and URL of the retweet itself,
   .map(({user, tweet}) => ({url: `https://twitter.com/${encodeURIComponent(user['screen_name'])}/status/${encodeURIComponent(tweet['id_str'])}`, text: tweet['full_text']}))
   // print results.
   .forEach(({url, text}) => console.log(url, text))
   ```

…*et voilà*:

> https://twitter.com/ThePSF/status/1398372497741946884

Answer (score 1):

[JamesTheAwesomeDude's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66483010/3013733) worked for me with some light modifications for the new twitter API:

```js
UserTweets = { /*PASTE HERE*/ }

// .timeline changed to .timeline_v2
UserTweets.data.user.result.timeline_v2.timeline.instructions
.filter(cmd => cmd['type'] == "TimelineAddEntries")
.map(cmd => cmd['entries']).flat()
.filter(entry => entry['content']['entryType'] == "TimelineTimelineItem" )
.map(entry => entry['content']['itemContent']['tweet_results']['result'])
// .user changed to .user_results.result
.map(tweet => [tweet['core']['user_results']['result']['legacy'], tweet['legacy']])
.filter(([user, tweet]) => tweet['retweeted_status_result'])
.map(([user, tweet]) => [`https://twitter.com/${user['screen_name']}/status/${tweet['id_str']}`, tweet['full_text']])
.forEach(([url, rt_text]) => console.log(url, rt_text))
```

Comment: I went ahead and merged your suggested changes -- in the future, don't be afraid to edit someone else's answer! A trivial fix to an objectively changed API is certainly not going to step on anyone's toes.